# Problemas em uma query SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, alias

Olá,

na query a seguir, é apresentado um erro na execução:

```
select 
    fto.id_taxon, 
    fto.cd_sexo as fto_cd_sexo, 
    fto.cd_idade as fto_idade, 
    x.ftv_cd_sexo, 
    x.ftv_cd_idade, 
    x.id_fv 
from 
    tb_foto_ocorrencia fto 
    left join (
        select 
            ftv.id_taxon as id_t, 
            ftv.cd_sexo as ftv_cd_sexo, 
            ftv.cd_idade as ftv_cd_idade, 
            ftv.id_foto_ocorrencia as id_fo, 
            ftv.id_foto_validacao as id_fv, 
            sum(
                case when ftv.id_taxon <> fto.id_taxon then 1 else 0 end
            ) 
        from 
            tb_foto_validacao ftv 
        group by 
            id_fo
    ) x on fto.id_foto_ocorrencia = x.id_fo 
WHERE 
    fto.fl_validado = 'n' 
ORDER BY 
    `fto`.`id_foto_ocorrencia` ASC
```

O erro apresentado é o seguinte:

> 1054 - Unknown column 'fto.id_taxon' in 'field list'

Mas como pode ser visto na query, os campos encontram-se definidos.

Comment: A tabela tem essa coluna `id_taxon`?

Comment: Sim, como pode ser visto no select externo.

Comment: O erro se dá na linha do case, quando se está comparando:

case when ftv.id_taxon <> fto.id_taxon then 1 else 0 end

Comment: De um nome para a coluna do `sum()` na subquery. O problema deve ser causado por isso.

Answer (score 0):

Ao tentar renomear a tabela para um nome temporário deve-se usar AS, ou seja, talvez estejam faltando AS entre o nome da tabela real e o temporário, logo depois de From.

```
select 
fto.id_taxon, 
fto.cd_sexo as fto_cd_sexo, 
fto.cd_idade as fto_idade, 
x.ftv_cd_sexo, 
x.ftv_cd_idade, 
x.id_fv from 
tb_foto_ocorrencia as fto 
left join (
    select 
        ftv.id_taxon as id_t, 
        ftv.cd_sexo as ftv_cd_sexo, 
        ftv.cd_idade as ftv_cd_idade, 
        ftv.id_foto_ocorrencia as id_fo, 
        ftv.id_foto_validacao as id_fv, 
        sum(
            case when ftv.id_taxon <> fto.id_taxon then 1 else 0 end
        ) 
    from 
        tb_foto_validacao as ftv 
    group by 
        id_fo
) x on fto.id_foto_ocorrencia = x.id_fo WHERE 
fto.fl_validado = 'n' ORDER BY 
`fto`.`id_foto_ocorrencia` ASC`
```

Answer (score 0):

Elliott,

O erro ocorre pois você está tentando acessar dados de uma consulta externa dentro de um sub-select. Para corrigir o erro, você deverá retirar o `fto.id_taxon` do `Sum()` no Sub Select.

Vejo que a coluna de soma não está sendo selecionada, sendo desnecessária sua soma. De quaquer forma, segue query corrigida, com a soma sendo selecionada no select principal.

```
select 
    fto.id_taxon, 
    fto.cd_sexo as fto_cd_sexo, 
    fto.cd_idade as fto_idade, 
    x.ftv_cd_sexo, 
    x.ftv_cd_idade, 
    x.id_fv,
    sum(case when x.id_t <> fto.id_taxon then 1 else 0 end) Soma
from 
    tb_foto_ocorrencia fto 
    left join (
        select 
            ftv.id_taxon as id_t, 
            ftv.cd_sexo as ftv_cd_sexo, 
            ftv.cd_idade as ftv_cd_idade, 
            ftv.id_foto_ocorrencia as id_fo, 
            ftv.id_foto_validacao as id_fv 
        from 
            tb_foto_validacao ftv 
        group by 
            id_fo
    ) x on fto.id_foto_ocorrencia = x.id_fo 
WHERE 
    fto.fl_validado = 'n' 
ORDER BY 
    `fto`.`id_foto_ocorrencia` ASC
```